# Running an OpenCl program

Tags: opencl

I'm new to OpenCl, and I'm having trouble running my first ever code. I have an ATI graphics card and I've done the necessary installation from here http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/ here. The following is the code I picked off that website to test my setup.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

int main(void) {
    // Create the two input vectors
   int i;
const int LIST_SIZE = 1024;
int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
    A[i] = i;
    B[i] = LIST_SIZE - i;
}

// Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
FILE *fp;
char *source_str;
size_t source_size;

fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");
if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
    exit(1);
}
source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
fclose( fp );

// Get platform and device information
cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1,
        &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

// Create an OpenCL context
cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

// Create a command queue
cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

// Create memory buffers on the device for each vector
cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);

// Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Create a program from the kernel source
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
        (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

// Build the program
ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// Create the OpenCL kernel
cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);

// Set the arguments of the kernel
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);

// Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE; // Process the entire lists
size_t local_item_size = 64; // Process in groups of 64
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
        &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
 int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
 ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), C, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Display the result to the screen
for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);

// Clean up
ret = clFlush(command_queue);
ret = clFinish(command_queue);
ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
ret = clReleaseContext(context);
free(A);
free(B);
free(C);
return 0;
}
```

...as per the instructions there. I keep getting "Failed to Load Kernel", which means it could not open the file.Where do I get the kernel source from?? Could someone please tell me how to get it to run??. Thanks in advance..

```
gcc -c -I /home/suraj/Desktop/Intern/softwares/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.7-lnx32
/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.7-RC-lnx32/include opencl.c -o oopencl.o

gcc opencl.o -o host -L /home/suraj/Desktop/Intern/softwares/AMD-APP-SDK
-v2.7-lnx32/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.7-RC-lnx32/lib/x86 -l OpenCL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through this exercise with this source code as well, and everything worked fine for me.  Did you grab the kernel program from [github](https://github.com/smistad/OpenCL-Getting-Started/)?  It is the third program down in the list called "vector_add_kernel.cl". The C program needs the kernel to actually run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the code from .github, and i'a all good.

Comment: @frodo Here I come a year later. I believe the way to thank is to accept the answer :)